# django-nonrel with mongodb relations

Tags: django, mongodb, google-app-engine, many-to-many, django-nonrel

I'm converting django with MySQL to django-nonrel with mongodb.
The biggest issue is the many to many relations.
I saw that ListField of models.ForeignKey doesn't work as expected.

Lets say that a Person can write many Posts, and each Post can be written by many Persons.
So the solution I've now seems to me really not efficient:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.TextField()
    posts = ListField(models.ForeignKey('Post'))

    def get_posts(self):
        posts_list = []
        for post_oid in self.posts:
            author = Post.objects.get(id=post_oid)
            posts_list.append(author)
    return posts_list

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    authors = ListField(models.ForeignKey(Person))

    def add_author(self, person):
        if self.has_author(person):
            return
        person.posts.append(ObjectId(self.id))
        person.save()
        self.authors.append(ObjectId(person.id))
        self.save()

    def get_authors(self):
        authors_list = []
        for person_oid in self.authors:
        author = Person.objects.get(id=person_oid)
            authors_list.append(author)
        return authors_list

    def has_author(self, person):
        return ObjectId(person.id) in self.authors
```

what is the right way to do it?

- I saw
  [How to convert django ManyToManyField into Django-nonrel Field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019445/how-to-convert-django-manytomanyfield-into-django-nonrel-field) but it didn't work for me for some reason.
- I'm using Django-nonrel 1.5

Thanks!

Comment: why use mongodb at all when django-nonrel would work much simpler with the nonrel datastore?

Comment: Hey, Because nonrel datastore doesn't have relationship (many-to-many..) and I need it

Comment: why not just use SQL then

Comment: I gave up on mongo, and I'm using MySQL. But the downside is the modification (tables, fields..), which is pretty difficult and "expensive"...